# How to prove continuity of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

I am struggeling with a prove tho show the continuity for the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-x^2}  \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$$

It would be very helpful to se a possible solution. I found one I didn't understand. Maybe the epsilon-delta criteria would be helpful, but I always struggle with that one. I need to prove that this series is continuous for every x of this function series.

Any ideas or complete solutions would be great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As $x\to n_-$ and $x\to n_+$ will not be equal, discontinuous.

Comment: Since each term is continuous on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, all you need to do is show the convergence of the series is uniform. This can be done with the Weierstrass M-Test.

Comment: @Nick Thanks a lot, I already considered that but came up with 1/n^2 as an sequence for M_n which is smaller or equal to the given series. That would mean the Weierstrass M-Test does not work here. Furthermore, can I directly assume without prove that each term is continuous?

Comment: @mathsstudent if you ignore the first term $n=1$  , then each term is bounded above by $1/(n^2-1)$. This converges, so ignoring the first term the series converges uniformly. Adding the first term back causes no issue toward continuity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant you are trying to prove the continuity for $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}\,:\, x \notin \mathbb{Z}\}$, since your function are not well defined in the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. In this case, we can fix an entire $k>0$ and consider $I_k=(-k,k) \backslash \mathbb{Z}$. You can use the Weirstrass test to conclude that the truncated series, from the $(k+1)$-th term forward, converges uniformly in $I_k$ since

$$\frac{1}{n^2-x^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2-k^2}.$$

Then, your series defines a continuous function in $I_k$ (for any $k$) and so it does in $\mathbb{R}\backslash{Z}$.